# Assert Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, assert

I have an application in iOS that asks for contact permission when you log in. This permission works fine if you hit "Allow" but sometime **the APP crashes when you hit "Not Allow"**. The function below is where it crashes on UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController...

```
- (BOOL) checkContactPermission {
__block BOOL authorized = NO;

// VAMOS A SOPORTAR A PARTIR DE IOS 9 POR LO QUE NO NECESITAMOS COMPROBARLO
// if ([CNContactStore class]) { }; //ios9 or later
CNEntityType entityType = CNEntityTypeContacts;

// Si no hemos pedido permiso de acceso antes lo pedimos
if([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:entityType] == CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    
    CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:entityType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(granted){
            NSLog(@"Contacts access Granted");
            authorized = YES;
        }
        // Si el usuario no nos da permiso mostramos un alert
        else {
            NSLog(@"Contacts access Denied");
            
            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                        alertControllerWithTitle:@"No se puede acceder a los contactos"
                                        message:@"La App necesita permiso de acceso a los contactos para mostrar el nombre de cada contacto en el listado de llamadas de la app."
                                        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                                 // Ok action example
                                                             }];
            [alert addAction:okAction];
            
            // Muestro el alert en el hilo principal
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]rootViewController]presentViewController:alert
                                                                                              animated:YES
                                                                                            completion:nil];
            });
        }
    }];
}
else if( [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:entityType] == CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    NSLog(@"Contacts access Authorized");
    authorized = YES;
}
return authorized;
}
```

This is what I get from xCode:

**OK -> Thread 25**
Thread 25 Queue : com.apple.root.default-qos (concurrent)

#0  0x00000001034c29d1 in __43-[GetContactsPlugin checkContactPermission]_block_invoke at /Users/vyorkmur/Documents/APP MiJazztel/Alicante/cordova10/mijazztel-application-typescript/platforms/ios/Mi Jazztel/Plugins/com.viewnext.plugin.getcontacts/GetContactsPlugin/GetContactsPlugin.m:198

**KO -- > Thread 4**
Thread 4 Queue : com.apple.root.default-qos (concurrent)

#23 0x0000000108340a19 in __43-[GetContactsPlugin checkContactPermission]_block_invoke at /Users/vyorkmur/Documents/APP MiJazztel/Alicante/cordova10/mijazztel-application-typescript/platforms/ios/Mi Jazztel/Plugins/com.viewnext.plugin.getcontacts/GetContactsPlugin/GetContactsPlugin.m:200

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put the following code inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                    alertControllerWithTitle:@"No se puede acceder a los contactos"
                                    message:@"La App necesita permiso de acceso a los contactos para mostrar el nombre de cada contacto en el listado de llamadas de la app."
                                    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                             // Ok action example
                                                         }];
        [alert addAction:okAction];
```

This way it loads the UIAllertController inside the main thread and doesnt crash.